# How we would create XML without any load on MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, node.js, phpwebsocket

I have a MYSQL database with an activity table whose rows are text statements(activities).
My challenge is to Push the latest activity into the ticker(An area where all my latest activity display) as soon as it gets inserted into the table . I can achieve this pinging the table every N seconds , but this consume a lots of memory resourses and Server.
So XML is the best way , but problem with how to create a XML file without Any load of MYSQL?
Please suggest me how to achieve this .
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The simple answer would be to have your PHP write your XML at the same time it does the database insert.

Comment: You can add a new table and safe the last updatetime in that table. Poll that table every x secs, and if the last updatetime is changed load the data from the database. The poll will have zero impact on your server that way.

Comment: Yaa i can achieve this via polling also but it also consumes the server and memory , there are so many technologies in the world: @ John : how to load the XML file without any load of MYSQL database ??

Comment: Trigger calling SP which writes the data to an XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets are designed to respond to PUSH requests (server to client) problematics, avoiding these costly "refresh every x seconds" operations.

Apparently HTML5 provides new tools to handle websockets, maybe you wish to have a look at them?

refer to: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Answer (score 2):

You can use node's [Net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module or [Socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/) to create and treat Websockets on the client and on the server.

As you handle a request from a user to push an activity into the table, you send a socket message to the client with this new activity, so you can update the ticker.

Comment: how can be implement in PHP , please give me a brief description about the technology with a bit code

Comment: Well, PHP can't handle real time sockets, so you will need another server (this one running Node) to handle the sockets. All you will need is javascript, on the client and on the server.